# Number of arrangements that contain at least 1 path from top to bottom of 2D matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, percolation

I have a $n\times n$ matrix of objects. $n'$ objects are black, and the rest $n^2-n'$ are white.

With that information, I can easily calculate the total number of black element arrangements that exist in the 2D matrix by using basic combinatorics: $C(n^2, n')$

Given the number of black elements present in the matrix, I aim to calculate the number of possible arrangements of those $ n'$ elements that contain at least one path from top to bottom of the grid (or vice-versa). However, I didn't find any direct formula or expression that relates $n^2$ and $n'$ to get that number.

How can I approach this problem without making an estimation or a simulation to obtain the number?

Edit: Consider a path from top to bottom in the matrix as a sequence of colored elements with the first one positioned in the first row of the grid and the last one in the corresponding opposite (last) row. For every contiguous pair of elements in the sequence, their distance must be 0; that is, they must be neighbors horizontally, vertically, or diagonally, and there is no limit or restriction for a path's length.

Also, note that this path definition doesn't include those whose starting and ending points are in the first-last columns of the grid.

Comment: To be clear: You want to calculate the number of ways to make a path of black entries from top to bottom? And what is a path--Can you only use horizontal and vertical adjacencies? Or can you also use diagonal adjacencies?

Comment: @paw88789 If the matrix contains $n'$ black entries, I want to calculate the number of arrangements of those $n'$ entries that contain at least one path from top to bottom. See the edit in which I added the definition of path. Thanks.

Comment: So, a path is a function $p$ from a set ${0,..,m-1}$ into the set $\{0,...,n-1\}\times\{0,...,n-1\}$ such that $row(p_0)=0$, $row(p_m-1)=n-1$ and for any $i<n-1$, $d(p_i+1,p_i)=1$ where $d(x,y)$ is the maximum of the number of rows apart and the number of columns apart. But, you want to know how many arrangements of black balls contain at least one such path.

Comment: @tony-dean Exactly; with that definition of path and $n'$ black elements in the grid, I want to count the number of arrangements of those black elements such that there is at least 1 path in the arrangement. 
Thanks.